# Randomly changing video src with JS

Tags: javascript, html, video, src

I'm trying to randomly change the video src using JS, a miserable fail

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<body style="width: 720px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">

<div id="mainBox">
  <div id="Vid" style="display: none">
    <video autoplay muted loop id="OracleVid" width="720" height="480">
      <source id="OracleVidSRC" src="css/cabenca9sClips_HD/cabenca9sClipHD_001.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

<button id="OracleButton"> Oracle </button>
  </div>
```

**and the JS**

```
var oracleButton = document.querySelector('#OracleButton');
var clip = document.querySelector('#OracleVidSRC');
var video = document.querySelector('#OracleVid');

var oracleVidArray = [
  "css/clips/video_001.mp4",
  "css/clips/video_002.mp4",
  "css/clips/video_003.mp4",
]

function oracleClicked() {
  var oracleVid = 
oracleVidArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*oracleVidArray.length)];
  clip.src = oracleVid;
  video.style = "display: block";
  video.load();
}

oracleButton.onclick = oracleClicked;
```

Can someone please tell me why it doesn't load a new video?
When I inspect, the src does change, but it just wont load.

I also get the "Uncaught TypeError: video.load is not a function" message in the console **:(**

**I would also accept a random src each new time the page loads.
Clicking the button would just make the video appear.**

```
Update: I have also tried this Clicked function
```

```
function oracleClicked() {
  var oracleVid = 
oracleVidArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*oracleVidArray.length)];
  var oracleVidSrc = video.createElement("source");
  oracleVidSrc.src = oracle
  clip.src = oracleVid;
  video.style = "display: block";
}
```

Now what I get in the console is "Uncaught TypeError: video.createElement is not a function"

-_-"

Thank you for the attention

Comment: Well if you want it to be random on each click, you need to randomly pick it on each click. You currently just pick it when the script renders first time.

Comment: Hi, and thanks. Ive tried adding the 'oracleVid=oracleVidArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*oracleVidArray.length)];' line to the Clicked function, but it wont load anyways

Comment: `var oracleVid = oracleVidArray....` has to be in the function

Comment: makes sense, I`ll add that to the code, but I still get "Uncaught TypeError: video.load is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues with your code:

Your `div` with `id="Vid"` is the one with  `style="display: none"`, yet in the `oracleClicked` function you are trying to set the `video.style = "display: block";` on the `video` element, which is from `querySelector("#OracleVid")`. Remove the outer div, and put that style on the `video` and the button will make it show as it is now targeting the correct element.

The line `var oracleVid = oracleVidArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * oracleVidArray.length)];` is not inside the `oracleClicked` function, so it is only being randomised once at page load. Move that line down into the function and the randomizer will work.

Button `onClick`s should be defined in the HTML, less error-prone and faster than using a query selector and adding it in the js.

---

Here's a fully working code snippet, with demo video files:

```js
var clip = document.querySelector("#OracleVidSRC");
var video = document.querySelector("#OracleVid");

var oracleVidArray = [
  "https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.webm",
  "https://ia600209.us.archive.org/20/items/ElephantsDream/ed_1024_512kb.mp4",
  "https://ia800300.us.archive.org/17/items/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4"
];

function oracleClicked() {
  clip.src = oracleVidArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * oracleVidArray.length)];;
  video.style = "display: block";
  video.load();
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="OracleVid" style="display: none" width="720" height="480">
  <source id="OracleVidSRC"/>
</video>

<button id="OracleButton" onClick="oracleClicked()">Oracle</button>
```